# How to change the mobile app ICON inside mobile quality assurance?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-qa

**Situation:**
You can create application inside MobileFirst Quality Assurance, after this creation no specific App Icon is displayed.

After the upload of the first version App Build Version into MobileFirst Quality Assurance  the App Icon changes to the Icon with is used for the application inside iOS or Android.

The observation is that ICON does not change, even when the upload of new builds of the App which contains a new ICON.

Inside the HELP System is no information related to the ICON management in AppSettings of the MFQA:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFRDS_6.3.0/com.ibm.mqa.uau.doc/topics/t_ManagingAppSettings.html

**Question:**
How can I change the ICON for the App inside MobileFirst Quality Assureance?

My question is very simple: Inside MobileFirst Quality Assureance you have a App list http://[YOURSERVER]/companies/2/application/list/.

How can you change the ICON for a APP in the MFQA server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MobileFirst Quality Assurance will show the icon that was added to the app. It does not provide a way to change the icon in the All Apps console.