# App ICON inside mobile quality assurance web console is not displayed?

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-qa

These are a different questions the other question was how to change an existing ICON inside the MobileFirst Quality Assurance Console!

Question difference is: a) general first upload of an ICON
                        b) change existing an existing ICON

**Situation:** 
You can create application inside MobileFirst Quality Assurance, after this creation no specific App Icon is displayed.
After the upload of the first Build Version for iOS a IPA file, into MobileFirst Quality Assurance, the App Icon does not displayed, as expected.

**Question:**
Which are the settings, which are required inside a xCode project from to display the ICON in the  MobileFirst Quality Assurance web console for the app list?
With simple MobileFirst Projects or simple iOS apps it works, but it seems in much customized an information is missing, but which?

Comment: Can you explain how this question is different from this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28984719/how-to-change-the-mobile-app-icon-inside-mobile-quality-assurance, please? They appear to be the same...

Comment: @Andrew Ferrier: These are a different questions the other question was how to change an existing ICON inside the MobileFirst Quality Assurance Console!

Question difference is: a) general first upload of an ICON b) change existing an existing ICON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MobileFirst Quality Assurance will show the icon that was added to the app. It does not provide a way to change the icon in the All Apps console.

That said, there is currently a bug preventing this icon from being displayed in the All Apps console There is no workaround for this, however a fix is being worked on.